# How to convert the following NASM code into AT&T syntax so as to fix the "cannot handle non-absolute segment in jmp" error

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, att

I am new at AT&T syntax. I want to convert the following NASM syntax code into AT&T syntax just for the sake of understanding.

My try to convert it into AT&T syntax:

```
lgdt (gdtpointer)

jmp $gdtcode, $_start

gdt:
.quad 0x0000000000000000

gdtcode: 
.word .- gdt
.quad 0x0020980000000000                   

gdtdata: 
.word .- gdt
.quad 0x0000900000000000                   

gdtpointer:
.word .-gdt-1
.quad gdt
```

---

```
Error: can't handle non absolute segment in `jmp'
```

The NASM code:

```
lgdt [gdt.pointer]          

jmp gdt.code:startLongMode

;Global Descriptor Table
gdt:
dq 0x0000000000000000               

.code equ $ - gdt
dq 0x0020980000000000                   

.data equ $ - gdt
dq 0x0000930000000000                   

.pointer:
dw $-gdt-1                  
dq gdt                  

                   ;Ref: Intel System Programming Manual V1 - 2.1.1.1
```

Comment: `.word .- gdt` actually emits a word into memory.  `.equ` is the GAS equivalent of NASM `equ`. See the manual: 
 https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Equ.html#Equ

Comment: thanks Peter, but the error I mentioned, still occurs! :(

Comment: What commands are you using to assemble this?

Comment: gcc -Wl,--oformat=binary -Wl,-Ttext=0x7c00 -Wl,--build-id=none     -nostartfiles -nostdlib -m32 -o test test.s

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `-m16`?  Also, you might need `-no-pie` in case your GCC defaults to passing `-pie`.  I think that only affects the linker, though, not the assembler.  Do you define `_start:` anywhere?

Comment: I guess the problem is with the jmp statement which seems to not handle the relative jmp CS:IP .. I tried gcc with -no-pie ... it still produces the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Should I provide the whole of the assembly code to analyze?

Comment: I don't do 16-bit stuff much at all, and not with AT&T syntax; maybe there's something obvious.  You don't need your whole source code, just a [mcve], emphasis on *complete*.  i.e. that you'd expect to assemble+link correctly, including all referenced labels and everything.

Comment: Oh My God, thanks so much @MichaelPetch ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GAS since the definition of your GDT appears after the `jmp $gdtcode, $_start`, the assembler will see the *JMP* and believe the symbol `gdtcode` is an external symbol (that will be relocated by the linker) and not a constant. Because of that it will complain about the non-absolute references.

You also improperly define your GDT by placing `.word .- gdt` after `gdtcode:` and `gdtdata`. Those lines will emit a 16-bit word into GDT where you don't want them.

I believe you might have been trying for something like the following. GDT is defined at some point **before** the *JMP*:

```
gdt:
.quad 0x0000000000000000

gdtcode:
.quad 0x0020980000000000

gdtdata:
.quad 0x0000900000000000

gdtpointer:
.word .-gdt-1
.quad gdt

CODE64_SEL = gdtcode-gdt
DATA64_SEL = gdtdata-gdt
```

And then at a later point in the file you can use a FAR *JMP* like this:

```
jmp $CODE64_SEL, $_start
```